# How can I initialize a val that need to be initialize through viewModelScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have the below code

```
class MainViewModel(private val todoDao: TodoDao) : ViewModel() {
    private var todoList = mutableStateListOf<TodoItem>()
    private val _todoListFlow = MutableStateFlow(todoList)

    val todoListFlow: StateFlow<List<TodoItem>> get() = _todoListFlow
    private var postExecute: (() -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        loadTodoList()
    }

    private fun loadTodoList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            todoDao.getAll().collect {
                todoList = it.toMutableStateList()
                _todoListFlow.value = todoList
                postExecute?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You notice the `var todoList` is `var`.

Since it get initialize only once, I hope to make it `val`. How is that possible, given it is initialized in the viewModelScope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you are using a mixture of `MutableStateFlow` and `SnapshotStateList` to end up with `MutableStateFlow<SnapshotStateList<TodoItem>>` when there is really no need for the `_todoListFlow`, but to answer your question simply initialise the `SnapshotStateList` then upon collection modify the data structure contents :

```
class MainViewModel(private val todoDao: TodoDao) : ViewModel() {
    private val todoList = mutableStateListOf<TodoItem>()
    private val _todoListFlow = MutableStateFlow(todoList)

    val todoListFlow: StateFlow<List<TodoItem>> get() = _todoListFlow
    private var postExecute: (() -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        loadTodoList()
    }

    private fun loadTodoList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            todoDao.getAll().collect {
                todoList.clear() // optional if getAll has multiple emissions?
                todoList.addAll(it)
                _todoListFlow.value = todoList
                postExecute?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```